# ORM HasLifecycleCallbacks does not work on abstract parent class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I have this abstract parent class with some restrictions.

```
namespace FileBundle\AbstractClass;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use FileBundle\Interfaces\IFileOid;
use FileBundle\Traits\TFileOid;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class AbstractFileOid implements IFileOid
{
    /**
     * Set trait
     */
    use TFileOid;

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile|null $fileTemp
     *
     * @return void
     */
    abstract public function init(UploadedFile $fileTemp = null);

    // and some next code here
}
```

As you can see, I use there a trait called "TFileOid" which contains some methods using orm lifecycle events like PostLoad(), PostPersist() etc..

And there is child class (entity) that extends the abstract parent:

```
namespace FileBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use FileBundle\AbstractClass\AbstractFileOid;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table("files")
 */
class MyFile extends AbstractFileOid
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $hash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "oid", nullable = true)
     */
    private $data;

    // and some next code
}
```

My issue is when I use ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks on the parent abstract class, the event methods in the trait will not be called. When I move the ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks to the child class, it will work. I tried a solution with "MappedSuperclass" definition on the parent, but without success.

Is there any way to define ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks on the parent and not on the child class?

Comment: remove the parenthesis at `@ORM\MappedSuperclass()` and `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`

Comment: I removed the parenthesis, but still not work

Comment: Even after cache cleared?

Comment: Yes. Symfony cache cleared and doctrine cache cleared by APCu. Still not work.

Comment: Are you using some `HasLifecycleCallbacks` on child?

Comment: No. I use only ORM\Entity() and ORM\Table("files") on child class

Comment: The parenthesis don't make a difference on annotations